# Longword variable Memory Location (Motorolla 68k)

Tags: assembly, cpu-word

I'm given a question as such:

```
A longword variable is stored in memory at address $001F00. What are the 
addresses  of  the longword  variables  immediately  before  and after  the variable?
```

Since a long word uses 32 bits, it would use up 8 of the nibbles of the address (001F00), but this address is only 6 bits, so I'm not sure how I would go about finding the next memory address, as well as the previous one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which size does the *smallest addressable unit* have? Is it an octett or something else?

Comment: The question doesn't specify :/, we generally deal with with octettes (8 nibbles in this class), but this question only has 6 of them.

Comment: Huh? An octett is 8 bits. A nibble is commonly 4 bits or some other convenient part of the smallest addressable unit if the latter is bigger.

Comment: I think I'm just confusing things around, we never actually learned the term nibble, I just thought it meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is shown as a hexadecimal number, but that is irrelevant. It's just a 24 bit number representing a location in memory.

Each address corresponds to one byte in memory. The address of byte following the one at `$001F00` is `$001F01`.

As a longword uses four bytes, the address of the next longword is four greater, i.e. `$001F04`. The previous longword is four less, i.e. `$001EFC`.

Comment: So the next one is $001f04, but how do you get the previous value, i.e how do you subtract to get $001EFC.

Comment: @user3739406: That's simply what you get when subtracting 4 from `$001F00`. The hexadecimal value `1F00` is the same as the decimal value `7936`. Subtracting 4 gives you `7932`, which is `1EFC` in hexadecimal.